# EFS Access Point EC2 mount timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-efs

I have an EFS which can be mounted on my EC2 without issue with this command:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1 myEfsId.efs.myRegion.amazonaws.com:/subfolder /mountDir
```

Now I would like to use Access Point to restrict the access of my EC2 to only my /subfolder/. Access Point is defined like this:

```
  EFSAccessPoint:
    Type: AWS::EFS::AccessPoint
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: myEFSId
      RootDirectory:
        CreationInfo:
          OwnerGid: "xxx"
          OwnerUid: "xxx"
          Permissions: "0750"
        Path: "/subfolder"
```

And my EC2 has a role containing these permissions:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
        "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:myRegion:myAccountId:access-point/myAccessPointId"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

But then, the following mount command leads to a timeout:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,accesspoint=myAccessPointId myEFSId /mountDir
```

What could be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you aren't using the [EFS mount helper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-mount-helper.html)? I think you have to use that to specify the access point attribute like you are trying to do. [The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-access-points.html) for mounting via an access point ***only*** shows that via the EFS mount helper.

Also, note that you need to specify the `iam` attribute to tell it to [use an IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-IAM-option.html), which is another thing I think you must use the EFS mount helper for.

Comment: You were right, thanks a lot! For EFS Mount Target, nfs4 works, but for Access Point, we need to use efs mount helper. So I used this: `mount -t efs -o tls,iam,accesspoint=myAccessPointId myEFSId.efs.myAWSRegion.amazonaws.com: /mountDir`. I was missing the `iam` option and to install `amazon-efs-utils` as detailed here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/overview-amazon-efs-utils.html

Answer (score 1):

your mount command seems a little wrong, I think you need to specify an accesspoint - try something like this

```
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,accesspoint=myAccessPointId myEfsId.efs.myRegion.amazonaws.com:/ /mountDir
```